# strace: print path instead of address

Tags: c, strace

I'm using strace to find possible errors in my program and I have this output:

```
open(0x7765533c, O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

How to get the value stored at this address or how to tell strace to print the path parameter?

Comment: Does strace always do that on your system, or does it just do that for your program? Because whenever I've used it, it has always shown shown the first parameter of `open` as a string.

Comment: No, for other calls -like for dynamic linking- strace shows the string instead. The open trace in this output is from a library I'm using, not from my own code.

Answer (score 0):

strace shows the pointer value when it *can't* show a string, because the pointer doesn't point to a valid memory location. In this case, the bytes of the pointer look suspiciously ASCII-like.

```
77  65  73  3c
 w   e   s   <
```

You've somehow extracted 4 bytes from your string and misinterpreted them as a pointer.

At least that's mostly what it looks like. There's one thing I can't explain, and that's how you got EACCES instead of EFAULT.